# How to create a transaction mechanism for accessing TWO different rest api resources?

Tags: rest, transactions

I want to perform two `POST` requests to two different endpoints, is it possible to do this in a transactional way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to perform two POST requests to two different endpoints, is it possible to do this in a transactional way?

No.

There's no rule that says that the effects of a POST will be scoped to precisely one resource.  On the web, we can submit one HTML form that changes multiple pages.  Implementations have a lot of freedom when processing a request (HTTP constrains message meaning, not handler implementations).

```
   POST /replace/these/resources/with/empty/documents
   Content-Type: text/plain

   /A
   /B/C
   /D/E/F?g
```

A piece that is missing, however, is the ability to communicate to general purpose components which resources *have been changed* when handling the POST request.  The mechanism described by [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) handles only a few simple cases, and does not (as far as I can tell) extend generally.

You get at most three

- effective request uri
- Location
- Content-Location

and both Location and Content-Location *mean* something, so you may end up with a mess if you try to force them out of their normal semantics.

You can, of course, send back response that includes in the payload a list of all of the resources that were changed by your transaction (if that's practical), but you don't have any way to lift that information into the metadata where general purpose components can use it.